# Validate canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I made this small drawing *app* using HTML5 Canvas, where kids can learn how to write letters and numbers. I want to know whether the letter/number has be drawn correctly.

I tried to do something like [this](http://liveweave.com/k9vRVh) to detect simple straight lines, like number '1'.

But I can't figure out how to detect complex shapes like numbers '2', '8' (well, anything other than straight lines)

- [Number 2](http://liveweave.com/MRWoju)
- [Number 8](http://liveweave.com/UsxKPw)

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to give them muscle-memory of writing "2" then you could put the outline of "2" on the canvas and let them fill that outline.

If more mousepoints are inside the outline than outside, then they probably drew the outline.

But, to "recall" a number and write it to the canvas you're close to needing character recognition(!).

I just googled and found this interesting attempt at number recognition.

http://www.heatonresearch.com/fun/ocr

**[ Update: example of simple "stay in the lines" game ]**

Here's how the game works:

- stroke an outline of the number "2" on the canvas with a white fill
- save an array of pixels using context.getImageData
- pixels inside the "2" will have alpha>20
- pixels outside the "2" will have alpha<20
- have the kids drag the mouse inside the "2"
- listen for mousemove events
- test the alpha value of the pixel under the mouse
- (alpha<20 means outside alpha>20 means inside the "2")
- if they are inside the "2" then add 1 to their score
- if they are outside the "2" then subtract 1 from their score
- (optionally) make the "2" green if they are inside as visual feedback of correctness

When they release the mouse, their score appears.  The score represents a count of mouse Inside minus mouse Outside the number.

Here's example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LL6ba/

**Mouse inside the number -- the number is green for positive visual feedback**

[image]

**Mouse outside the number -- no positive visual feedback**

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: white; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
    var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();


    ctx.font="216px arial";
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    ctx.fillText("2",100,200);
    ctx.strokeText("2",100,200);

    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;
    var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch);
    var data=imgData.data;

    var isDown=false;
    var wasInside=true;
    var score=0;

    function draw(mouseX,mouseY){

        var alpha = data[((cw*mouseY)+mouseX)*4+3];

        score+=(alpha>19?1:-1);

        if(alpha<20 && wasInside){
            wasInside=false;
            ctx.fillStyle="white";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
            ctx.fillStyle="white";
            ctx.fillText("2",100,200);
            ctx.strokeText("2",100,200);
        }else if(alpha>19 && !wasInside){
            wasInside=true;
            ctx.fillStyle="white";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
            ctx.fillStyle="green";
            ctx.fillText("2",100,200);
            ctx.strokeText("2",100,200);
        }

    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      var alpha = data[((cw*mouseY)+mouseX)*4+3];
      wasInside=(alpha<20);
      score=0;
      isDown=true;
      draw(mouseX,mouseY);
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      isDown=false;
      $("#score").text("Score: "+score);
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      if(!isDown){return;}
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      draw(mouseX,mouseY);
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <h4>Drag inside the number<br>Number stays green while you're inside.</h4>
    <h3 id="score">Score:</h3>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just want to give them muscle-memory. Could you please explain or give pointers on how I can know if more mousepoints are inside?

Comment: Sure. I updated my answer to include a simple game demo that scores how well the child dragged inside the number.  My game version is very plain.  I'm sure you can "fancy it up" for the kids!

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex area, probably outside the scope of SO, but look into things such as neural networks or online recognition (while they draw).

Here is a neural network approach (source code in C++; should be somewhat easy to translate to JavaScript) (it comes with a weight file):
**➔ [Neural Network for Recognition of Handwritten Digits](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16650/Neural-Network-for-Recognition-of-Handwritten-Digi?fid=364895&fr=1)**

Here is an on-line approach using multiple convolution neural network (C# code):
**➔ [Online handwriting recognition using multi convolution neural networks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/523074/Online-handwriting-recognition-using-multi-convolu)**

More on the topic:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handwriting_movement_analysis
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handwriting_recognition